# Python Multiprocessing TypeError: can't pickle generator objects

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to map a function call to a pool. I am using the fixes from other similar threads involving calling functions with multiple arguments. I cannot include a more comprehensive example as the train methods for the strategy classes are very long and complicated and the data sets are large:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial
from numpy import array_split

def call_train(signals, args):
    return args[0].train(signals, args[1])

pool = mp.Pool()

chunks = array_split(data.train_signals, pool._processes)
res = pool.map(partial(call_train, [strat, data.train_md]), chunks)
```

In the above, strat is a python object and both data.train_signals and data.train_md are pandas dataframes.

The error is as follows:

```
File "/home/jason/PycharmProjects/backtester/core/backtester.py", line 51, in evaluate
res = pool.map(partial(call_train, [strat, data.train_md]), chunks)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
raise self._value
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 385, in _handle_tasks
put(task)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle generator objects
```

Comment: What are (and the types of) `strat` and `data.train_md` ?

Comment: Just edited them in.

Comment: Since DataFrames and numpy arrays are pickleable - that hints you have something in `strat` that is a generator that can't directly be pickled... (eg: `strat` or something `strat` contains can't be pickled implicitly...)

Comment: Amazing! Nested 3 objects deep I had a (for i in iterable) instead of a [for i in iterable], thanks so much for your help! Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Umm... an answer useful to future readers (if one doesn't already exist) should ideally explain how to find such things and then ways on how to address them. I don't have time to do that right now... and leaving an answer of "your object has a generator somewhere in it" isn't more than a comment... Feel free to self-answer though!

Comment: Also for future readers, the `dill` package allows to serialize some objects that `pickle` can not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update:

Nested 3 objects deep under my `strat` class I had a generator I had forgotten about.

Answer (score -1):

Set use_multiprocessing=False in fit_generator, this somehow allows to walk-around the problem.

Comment: what is fit_generator? No context for this comment.